# Convert string of encoded escape sequences to Unicode in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, character-encoding

I'm attempting to decode a Python string containing a series of Shift-JIS escape sequences in Python. When I create a bytes literal containing the sequences, I can use `decode('shift-jis')` to get the expected result.

```
>>> seq = b'\201u\202\240\202\246\202\244\202\242\202\250\201v'
>>> seq.decode("shift-jis")
'「あえういお」'
```

The problem is that the sequences are passed in as a plain Python string. When I use `str.encode`, the sequence is interpreted as Unicode and extra bytes of `\xc2` are inserted:

```
>>> seq = "\201u\202\240\202\246\202\244\202\242\202\250\201v"
>>> str.encode(seq)
b'\xc2\x81u\xc2\x82\xc2\xa0\xc2\x82\xc2\xa6\xc2\x82\xc2\xa4\xc2\x82\xc2\xa2\xc2\x82\xc2\xa8\xc2\x81v'
```

Is there a way to directly convert a Python string containing encoded escape sequences into a bytes literal, in the same way as placing a `b` in front of a string produces a bytes literal with the escaped characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Str.encode defaults to using utf-8 encoding.  hence you get the utf-8 \xc2 prefixes.  (Check Wikipedia for details if you want.) What you want instead is for codepoints 0 to 255 to be turned into bytes 0 to 255.  In others words, the same data in an object of a different class.  Latin-1 does this.

```
>>> seqb = seq.encode('latin-1')
>>> seqb.decode('shift-jis')
'「あえういお」'
```